# How can I modify every other element in an array using JS?

Tags: javascript

So the data is like this:

```
let array = ["Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes"];
```

**Expected Result:**

```
array = ["Yes", "", "Yes", ""];
```

I've seen some answers on Stackoverflow, but I haven't found one that shows how to modify every other element. Most show how to filter, like this one:

```
let x = arrar.filter((element, index) => {
  return index % 2 === 0;
})
```

Appreciate your help!

Comment: If you want only want to modify every odd index, then you should use the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method, then either modify the element when it is odd or return the unaltered value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Emiel pointed out in the comments, you don't want to use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) here as that would reduce your original array. Instead use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
let array = ["Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes"];

let x = array.map((element, index) => {
  return (index % 2 === 0) ? element : '';
})

console.log(x)
```

Comment: Right on! I understand that folks are to keep a good quality when it comes to Q&A and some questions may sound stupid to the, but sometimes it's just a bit details...especially to who's learning! Thanks for your input. Saved me here! Cheers]